# Theano tensor import error

Tags: python, theano

I have been trying to import `theano.tensor` in my code.
I have used `theano.tensor` before. All of my previous code importing `theano.tensor` works perfectly in my machine. Now I am trying to write another script importing the tensor from theano and I am getting the following exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 2, in <module>
    import theano.tensor as T
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from theano.gof import (
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/gof/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from theano.gof.opt import (
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pdb
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pdb.py", line 75, in <module>
    import code
  File "/localtmp/saikat/CovInfo/Closure/code.py", line 2, in <module>
    import theano.tensor as T
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from theano.tensor.basic import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 17, in <module>
    from theano.tensor import elemwise
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/elemwise.py", line 13, in <module>
    from theano import scalar
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/scalar/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/scalar/basic.py", line 25, in <module>
    from theano import gof, printing
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/printing.py", line 22, in <module>
    from theano.compile import Function, debugmode, SharedVariable
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 22, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/compile/mode.py", line 77, in <module>
    OPT_NONE = gof.Query(include=[], exclude=exclude)
AttributeError: module 'theano.gof' has no attribute 'Query'
```

I cannot find any plausible reason for this exception.

Comment: what is the filename of your script?

Comment: `code.py` what does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i got your problem. See in the error log:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/pdb.py", line 75, in <module>
    import code
```

I believe there is another script called `code.py` in `Theano` which gets called from `pdb.py` when python interpreter executes your script which is also named as `code.py`.  I am guessing python interpreter is mixing up these two scripts and executing the wrong one! You can change the filename and check whether the error disappear or not.

Comment: Thanks @wasi-ahmad